# Xamarin.Forms MvvM Prism Software and Hardware Back Button

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvm, prism

I have problem with implementation Code which resolve problem with confirm software nad hardware button back. I need confirm and save state page field. When confirm is true and save state have no error I want close page and when confirm is false or save state have error I want stop closing page. I use xamarin.forms with mvvm prism.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean want to custom the method of *Software* and *Hardware* Back Button of **Android** device, you could override `OnOptionsItemSelected` and `OnKeyDown` method in **MainActivity.cs** to achieve that.

**Software Back** Button code in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   ...
   Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
   SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   SupportActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled(true);
}

public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    if(item.ItemId == Android.Resource.Id.Home)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("software back button press");
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Hardware Back** Button code in `MainActivity.cs`:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if(e.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && keyCode == Keycode.Back)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hardware back button press");
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. Problem is that I use Prism and I need save data do DB from Page field when user confirm close page. Use MainActivity.cs is non comfortable when I must send data.

Comment: @PiotrMysłek Okey, that's no problem. You could use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center) to send message to Prism with data.

Comment: Could You send me example with MessagingCenter and use MainActivity.cs for confirm back button?

Comment: @PiotrMysłek Sorry, it depends on your logic. But it's easy to use MessageCenter. You could explains more logic information in question. And add my code in your project to have a try.

Comment: Ok. No problem. Where I find IMenuItem.

Comment: I mus use this in form ex. Page1.xaml.cs. In this code I don't have Android.Views.IMenuItem

Comment: @PiotrMysłek Do you have a Android solution in your project? You could share a screenshot of the folder of project.